# Dealing with array of IntPtr

Tags: c#, c++, interop, native, intptr

I think I'm close and I bet the solution is something stupid.

I have a C++ native DLL where I define the following function:

```
DllExport bool __stdcall Open(const char* filePath, int *numFrames, void** data);
{
  //creates the list of arrays here... don't worry, lifetime is managed somewhere else

  //foreach item of the list:
  {
      BYTE* pByte = GetArray(i);

      //here's where my problem lives
      *(data + i * sizeofarray) = pByte;
  }
  *numFrames = total number of items in the list
  return true;
}
```

Basically, given a file path, this function creates a list of byte arrays (BYTE*) and should return a list of pointers via the data param. Each pointing to a different byte array.

I want to pass an array of IntPtr from C# and be able to marshal each individual array in order. Here's the code I'm using:

```
    [DllImport("mydll.dll",EntryPoint = "Open")]
    private static extern bool MyOpen(
      string filePath, out int numFrames, out IntPtr[] ptr);

    internal static bool Open(
      string filePath, out int numFrames, out Bitmap[] images)
    {
        var ptrList = new IntPtr[512];

        MyOpen(filePath, out numFrames, out ptrList);

        images = new Bitmap[numFrames];
        var len = 100; //for sake of simplicity
        for (int i=0; i<numFrames;i++)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[len];
            Marshal.Copy(ptrList[i], buffer, 0, len);

            images[i] = CreateBitmapFromBuffer(buffer, height, width);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Problem is in my C++ code. When I assign *(data + i * sizeofarray) = pByte; it corrupts the array of pointers... what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Just started to create a new solution to isolate concepts and already found something very weird. Take a look:

*C# code*

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("ArrayProvider.dll")]
    private static extern bool Open(out int n, ref IntPtr[] ptr);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n;

        var pList = new IntPtr[10];

        Program.Open(out n, ref pList);

        foreach (var p in pList)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(p.ToInt32().ToString("X"));
        }
    }
}
```

*C++ code*

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

extern "C" {

DllExport bool __stdcall Open(int *n, void** data)
{
return true;
}

}
```

Before the call to native code, pList has 10 IntPtr.Zero elements. After returning from native call, it has only one... something wrong... and it also happens if I replace void** by BYTE**

Comment: I'm not sure that `*(data + i * sizeofarray)` makes sense even if `data` were a `char*` (or pointer to anything other than `void`) - but then it's not really clear to me what exactly is supposed to be stored wherever `data` is pointing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime will have no clue to the length of the array when receiving unmanaged arrays, you need to use the [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) in conjunction with the [SizeParamIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex.aspx) field to specify the length of the array. There's an example of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.sizeparamindex.aspx).

You also don't need to define the method signature as ref IntPtr[] for the array, use the [InAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.inattribute.aspx) and [OutAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx).

E.x.:

```
private static extern bool Open(out int n,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0)] [In,Out] IntPtr[] ptr);
```

Comment: I was going to post the answer and saw yours... replacing "ref" by "[In, Out]" did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
out IntPtr[] ptr
```

to

```
ref IntPtr[] ptr
```

There is a subtle difference between the 2.

Update:

Try:

```
data[i] = pByte
```

Comment: Changed and still have an access violation when I return from unmanaged

Comment: One more detail... after the AV if I choose to "break", my ptrList has length 1 instead of 512...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the update... tried and still have an AV. I give up. The problem must be somewhere else. I'll make a simple demo solution to isolate the problem and I'll come back to my production code once I figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

How can you write this where **data** is `void*` type:

```
 //you cannot do such pointer arithmetic on void* type.
 *(data + i * sizeofarray) = pByte;
```

Change this to either type `char*` or `int*`.

Also, use `ref` instead of `out` for the last argument here:

```
MyOpen(filePath, out numFrames, out ptrList); //wrong
```

This is corrected one:

```
MyOpen(filePath, out numFrames, ref ptrList); //correct
```

You've to change the method signature accordingly.

Comment: `ref` is not needed for `numFrames`. I doubt changing the `void*` to something else would make any difference.

Comment: @leppie : how would the pointer arithmetic make sense if it's using `void*` type?

Comment: I think that's where my confusion resides. I decided to use void** because my GetArray returns a BYTE*... can I simply replace void** by BYTE**?

Comment: @Nawaz: the size of void* is pretty well known, but now that you said it, I suspect `data[i] = pByte` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Padu : that is better. because that way, compiler can know the size of each element the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @Nawaz: But since my void** data is supposed to be an array of pointers (to a byte*), shouldn't each element of that array be a 32 bit integer?

Comment: @Padu : oops... I didn;t notice that it's not `void*`... it's actually `void**`. I think it should work now. But I still think using void is not a good idea. BYTE is still better!

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that you want

```
*(data + i * sizeofarray) = pByte;
```

to be something more like

```
data[i] = pByte;
```

So you'll be storing an array of pointers in whatever `data` is pointing to.

Comment: I'll try that. Each element of data points to a BYTE* that contains raw monochrome bytes for an image

Comment: One more time for good luck? I have said this twice already :)